# Error 400 to limit number in Openweathermap API

Tags: python, runtime-error, openweathermap

I'm trying to use Openweathermap and I'm using their docs to get the calls.

I don't know why but I get always this error:

```
{'cod': '400', 'message': '{limit} is not a number'}
```

This is my code:

```
import requests
import json

API_KEY = "49edcdeb737a08b5371c42f85fb4ce3d"
weather_url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q={city_name},{country_code}&limit={limit}&appid="
final_url = weather_url + API_KEY

limit = "1"
city_name = "Brindisi"
country_code = "3166"

weather_data = requests.get(final_url).json()

print(weather_data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not replacing the query parameters with actual values. `q={city_name},{country_code}&limit={limit}` is hard coded in the url and is invalid.

You can use the `F-string` in python to replace placeholder value with actual value.

```
limit = "1"
city_name = "Brindisi"
country_code = "3166"

weather_url = f"http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q={city_name},{country_code}&limit={limit}&appid="
final_url = weather_url + API_KEY
```